# Angular 6 Component Inheritance

Tags: angular, inheritance, components

I'm looking for the way to go for reusing and extending components in other modules. I've found angular's dynamic component loading on their docs site, but I do not know if thats the correct way for extending components.

I'm currently upgrading an AngularJS app which consists of two angularJs modules. The main module which is used by clients and another module which extends parts of the main module and is used by internals.

In AngularJS we just extended directives and services from the main app and bootstrapped them separately.

I would like to do similar in Angular 6. I use a base module, which consists of all the components used in both apps. In both apps I extend them and load them via dynamic component loading.

I setup a stackblitz example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-inheritance-example

I would love to know if that's a way to go or if I am completely on the wrong path.

I do not like having to use a helper component for that. I would like to have a kind of interceptor whichs load the right component on rendering the selector, but I do not know if thats possible.

**EDIT:**

Thats the way we did it in angularjs:

`angular.module('childApp').directive('parentDirective', () => return new OverriddenDirective())`

`angular.module('parentApp').run(...)`
`angular.module('childApp').run(...)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Feel free to share the angularejs code too.

Comment: This is pretty easy, you just need to export components aka. add them to the `exports` in the module decorator. ( it is all about child modules in application)

Comment: @Kraken I my example I export the NiceComponent already in BaseModule. In future I would like to use BaseModule to do the routing and provide a single route template for both apps. For example: Client App and Admin App should share the same route. In admin app the shared component should show a little bit more than in client app.

Comment: @aloisdg thank you for the welcome :-) In angularjs we just bootstrap the child app with the extended classes after bootstrapping the parent app. 

`angular.module('childApp').directive('parentDirective', () => return new OverriddenDirective())`
  
`angular.module('parentApp').run(...)`  
`angular.module('childApp').run(...)`